# SQL Server (Table might be locked by some process) - how to release

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012. I am bot able to select rows from a table "Prime.ProductMaster".

When I write query like `Select * from Prime.ProductMaster` then it continue executing forever.

When I run the same query with Nolock. i.e `Select * from Prime.ProductMaster WITH(NOLOCK)` it executes.

I have investigated on this and found the problem that after row No 2778 the problem exists. I think table might be locked by some other process.

Could anyone please help me how to overcome from this issue. I cant restart sql server as it is shared by many people.

[image]

Comment: run sp_who2 - to check if there are any locking/blocking or you can query the DMV's related to locking and blocking.

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on our SQL instance name and view `Activity Monitor`, alternately, click the icon on the far right of your screen shot.

Underneath `Resource Waits` you should see a row that indicates any `Lock` that might be held. If this reads `0` there are no locks, otherwise some other process is creating and holding a `Lock` on the table or rows.

Underneath `Processes`, you should be able to see active connections, which you can filter by `Database` and in your case, perhaps `Wait Type`, to identify the process that is holding the `Lock`. Whilst this may indicate the cause and you could simply right click and `kill process`, depending on the application scenario I would use this information to investigate the issue/code that is causing this `Lock`.

If it's not clear, you may need to profile your database using `SQL Server Profiler` to track the root cause of the `Lock`. I would suggest setting up the profiler to check for `Locks` and possible `Deadlocks` to filter out "noise" from the trace.

If you need info on how to profile `Locks`,  take a look at [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBRA4rIXRig).